# fpm / RPM: How to use fpm to create multiple smaller rpm files, using a directory as source?

Tags: centos7, rpm, rpmbuild

We have a situation that we have a folder which is pretty large (many GB), and we need to pack the content of the folder into rpm file (we can't split the folder into multiple folders due to some restrictions).

However, our downstream system has size limit on each rpm file it can transfer & process (this can't be changed).

So instead of creating one big rpm file from the content of the folder, we need to create multiple smaller rpm files.

Is this doable using fpm? (we are on CentOS 7, by the way)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Is big src.rpm feasible? Then:

```
foo.spec:
Name: foo
Source0: big.tar.gz
Requires: %{name}-part1
Requires: %{name}-part2

%package part1
Summary: Part1 of %{name}

%description
Includes some cool part1.

%package part2
Summary: Part2 of %{name}

%description
Includes less cool part2.

...
# prep, build, install section is the same as original spec

%files
%doc README

%files part1
/some/dir/with/part1

%files part2
/some/dir/with/part2
```

The different way to implement `%files` can be:

```
%files part1
/your/project/
%exclude /your/project/part2

%files part2
/your/project/part2
```

This creates two rpm packages `foo-part1` and `foo-part2`. You can actually make as many subpackages as you want. E.g. texlive src.rpm makes dozens of subpackages. And there is one package `foo` which contains nothing but one file, and it requires all these parts.

Comment: Thanks. I will see if I can find a way to give it a try. At the moment, I used a similar but hacky way: I first create 1 package based on one (largest) sub folder. Then remove that subfolder, then create the second package. These 2 packages are independent of each other, so I have to be careful when install them. But it works for my particular case.